# Gap on bottom of the page on mobile browsers when using height 100vh/100%

Tags: android, html, css

I have a page with a few divs (class="full") that I want to be as high as the viewport of the user is. It works on Desktop (Ubuntu, Firefox) but not on mobile (Android, Chrome). My smartphone shows a small white gap at the bottom.

```
div.full {
    min-height: 100vh !important;
}

html,body {
    min-height: 100vh !important;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

body {
    position: relative; 
    background: url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;  
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

When I scroll on the page, this gap increases. It seems like it is the height of my android status bar + the address bar of chrome when I scrolled down and just the height of the status bar when I did not scroll.

I also tried 100% instead of 100vh, it didn't help.

If I remove

```
height:100vh;
```

from the html, body block the gap disappears, but then I have a new problem: The background image is scaled up a lot and gets blurred...

How can I make a div exactly 100% high on all devices (even when scrolling)?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it working now. The code in the question was correct, but I also had this code in my CSS:

```
.ref-logo {
    width: 400px;       
}
```

This seems to have caused my page to be rescaled. I noticed this because the navbar-button was only shown when I scrolled to the right...

This works now:

```
.ref-logo {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

I know why I am no web developer :P